# Tiny text field script

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm looking to modify the pagination in Magento in an order to give user an opportunity to switch to any page at any moment. To my mind it can be a text field, when somebody enters page number x, it will redirect to http://www.domainname.com/catalogpage.html?p=x

Any ideas of this php line?

Comment: Tap the checkmark (accept). It means that Your problem is solved. It is under vote count of my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="catalogpage.html" method="post">
<input type="text" name="p">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Works?